# Limiting analysis to particular area of larger DTM using Whitebox GAT?

Tags: dem, geoprocessing, extents, whitebox-gat

I am new at using Whitebox GAT, which I find very interesting.

When one runs an analysis, is there any possibility to limit the processing to a section of the input DTM, or does the latter have to be clipped exactly to the extent of the study area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no concept of a global work area in Whitebox GAT. Your best way forward is simply to clip the data layers to your area of interest using the **Clip Raster To Polygon** (raster data clipped to vector polygon) or **Clip** (vector clipped to vector polygon) tools.